# try-catch instead of if in edge cases

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Would it be a good idea to replace the if statements with try-catch in the following usecases (performance and readability wise?):

**Example 1**

```
public static void AddInitializable(GameObject initializable)
{
    if(!HasInstance)
    { // this should only happen if I have forgotten to instantiate the GameManager manually
        Debug.LogWarning("GameManager not found.");
        return;
    }

    instance.initializables.Add(initializable);
    initializable.SetActive(false);
}

public static void AddInitializable2(GameObject initializable)
{
    try
    {
        instance.initializables.Add(initializable);
        initializable.SetActive(false);
    }
    catch
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("GameManager not found.");
    }
}
```

**Example 2**

```
public static void Init(int v)
{
    if(!HasInstance)
    {// this should happen only once
        instance = this;
    }

    instance.alj = v;
}

public static void Init2(int v)
{
    try
    {
        instance.alj = v;
    }
    catch
    {
        instance = this;
        Init(v);
    }
}
```

Edit:

Question 2: How many Exceptions can I get to be still performance positive?

Comment: No, intentionally causing exceptions and using it to control your program flow is discouraged.

Comment: No! No! No! Exceptions are incredibly expensive in terms of memory and processing time. They are also the equivalent of a `goto` in that your code can throw an exception anywhere and you immediately end up in your exception handler. You should only ever catch ***specific*** exceptions that you can ***meaningfully*** handle. Otherwise you should always write code that ***avoids*** exceptions. Always.

Comment: Answer to question 2: ZERO!

Comment: Here is the absolute, number one read on exceptions in C#, thanks to the legendary Eric Lippert: https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: I've always wondered why `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` is usually used in Microsoft's sample code, rather than `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` ...

Comment: If the code is broken if the `GameManager` is not found, you should certainly throw an `InvalidOperationException` because (from the comment) this is a coding error and not an environmental error. It's similar to throwing `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception if a method parameter is out of range.

Comment: @MatthewWatson if it is then initializing it anyway though (example 2) I think waiting for an exception (especially in OPs case just any) is very wrong and expensive if anyway you can rather check a simple bool and then lazy initialize the instance. Actually I would though not use a bool at all but rather `if(instance == null) { instance = this; }`

Comment: @derHugo I agree - it should just throw the exception so the programmer knows they need to fix their code. That's what I meant by `If the code is broken if the GameManager is not found`. If you're fixing it up, then the code is not considered broken since it will work. I would consider the code broken, throw the exception, and NOT handle the exception, but fix the code instead if I saw the exception occuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with [PMF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70861021/7111561): **Depends**!

On your specific use case and in specific whether something is **your fault** or something **you can't control / predict**.

So in general I'd say there are **three** ways of how to **handle** stuff that isn't behaving as expected

- A) let throw an exception to indicate that this is really bad and there is no way to recover => and most probably crash your app

  This usually makes totally sense on development time because while debugging you explicitly **want** your app to crash so you can find and fix the issue.

  This should be happening for everything where the cause is basically something that **you** messed up and can be fixed by you. (In your case `instance` not initialized correctly)
- B) return something e.g. `false` to indicate that something went bad but allow this to be handled by the code and e.g. try something else.

  In my eyes this should be the preferred way of dealing with stuff **you can't control yourself** like e.g. user input and other unpredictable conditions like internet connectivity etc.
- C) Just ignore it and do nothing at all.

  Depends of course on what exactly you are doing but this should actually happen almost never. For a User this can be extremely frustrating and also for you as developer it makes debugging hard to impossible!

  In combination with `B` of course this is valid since something else will already have delt with the issue.

And to add just in general unless you work on some core / reused library I would actually never **throw** exceptions myself except you are re-throwing caught ones to add additional debugging information. This basically falls under "you can't control" how others will use your library -> this basically from your perspective falls under user input ;)

---

Now all three options can be achieved by `try - catch` or `if` checks internally of course and it depends on your specific case which way you want to go.

Some thoughts of mine on this

- Readability wise I would prefer the `if` already alone because it makes clear exactly which condition is checked. When I see a `try - catch` I don't know exactly at which point which exact exception might be thrown on first glance.

  Thus using `try - catch` as a replacement for `if` just obscures what exactly is failing and makes debugging hard to impossible
- Exceptions are quite expensive! So performance wise I would say use `if` wherever possible.
- There are cases though - and in my opinion these are the only ones where `try - catch` would be allowed - where you use a library and there simply is no way to prevent an exception.

---

Example: FileIO

- the file you want to access does not exist

  -> You don't need `try - catch` for this (in my eyes it would be the lazy way). This is something you can and should actually check first `if(!File.Exists(...))` so your program can correctly deal with it and handle that case (e.g. you might want to tell the user instead of simply crash or doing nothing).
- The file is currently opened by another program so you can't write to it.

  -> There is no way to find this out beforehand. You will get an exception and can't avoid it. Here you want to `try - catch` in order to still allow your code to deal with such case (as before e.g. tell the user instead of simply crash).

But then how you actually deal with them again depends:

- If you e.g. use some hardcoded paths and these files definitely should be there -> **Exception** because it means **you** as developer messed something up.
- If the path comes from user input -> **Catch** because this is something you as **developer can't control** but don't just want your app to crash, rather show a hint to the user that he messed it up.

---

Now in your use case the `Example 1` both of your solutions seem pretty bad to me. You go with the last option `C` and just ignore the call - a user won't see the warning and also a developer might just not note / ignore it.

You definitely **want** to get an Exception here if this means that your app will not behave correctly and not catch it at all!

In general there is no need for a special `bool` flag. I would rather go with

```
if(instance == null)
{
    Debug.LogError(...);
    return;
}
```

Because this is most probably a more severe error not only a warning so it at least gains visibility.

In your `Example 2` you actually have kind of a lazy initialization anyway so either way the call itself is basically valid.

In such case though again this is something you can easily check and I would not wait for an exception (especially not simply **any**) because I already **know** that there definitely will be one at least once.

In my opinion this should rather be

```
if(instance == null)
{
    // I have put `???` because, well, in a "static" method there is no "this" so 
    // I wonder where the instance should come from in that case ;)
    instance = ???;
}

instance.alj = v;
```

Comment: Good answer, but I disagree that you should never throw exceptions yourself. Particularly when writing a library, it makes sense to throw exceptions when something unexpectedly happens (a required file is not there, a communication link times out, etc.) because that doesn't require adding return codes to all functions in the possible call stack.

Comment: @PMF I didn't say **never** throw them. I said you should **only** throw it in exactly that case that you make your own library used by others which basically falls under the case "you can't control it" since you don't know how others will use your library ;) I hope it's a bit clearer now

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

Try-blocks are generally cheap, so when the exception is *not* thrown, that would be an acceptable solution. But: In your case, if the condition is not satisfied (meaning the thing was not initialized before that method was called), this is a programming error, not something that should ever happen in the finished program. It is perfectly valid that such errors crash the program. Makes spotting the bugs and fixing them much easier in development, and avoids that you silently hide it (in example 1, you silently don't do anything, which might cause confusing behavior later).

So: If it would be a programming error, don't use an exception handler, nor a test (except maybe an Assert). Just let the program crash (with a NullReferenceException in this case).

Comment: I really don't like your "It depends". I don't think it depends at all. If you write a `try`/`catch` that never throws then it is cheap, but 100% redundant. In any case, though, it gives a false sense of security. If you can recognised how to code to avoid exceptions then you are able to write more solid code. Exception handle is a crutch otherwise.

Comment: The rest of your answer is excellent, though. Really good.

Comment: @Enigmativity It certainly does depend. If you're doing method parameter validation, then you certainly DO want to throw. If your code is correct, such exceptions will never be thrown, but I totally disagree that this means you shouldn't throw them. Not only do such exceptions ensure that the method is called correctly, they also provide a degree of documentation-via-code.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - If you're dealing with bone-headed arguments - like passing `0` as the denominator in a division operator - then you need to through exceptions because you can't ***meaningfully*** handle the exception. Otherwise the calling code should be responsible for what it sends.

Comment: @Enigmativity I wrote "It depends" because how to handle the case depends on the nature of exceptions to be expected. In this case, I assume the final program would never throw, so it's no performance penalty, which was the OPs primary concern.

Answer (score 1):

To my point of view, this is not a good idea.

We usually use try catch when we know what kind of exceptions will appear in the context, and hence a catch without exception type is not a good practice. Moreover, try catch is not expensive **only if the exception rarely happens**.

In your scenario, since you already know the only problem is that the property HasInstance may be false, you could directly check it with if statement. Using try catch seems more like a cost here, although it works. This seems like you are expecting an error, and you just ignore that error because its message does not matter.

Besides, I see you are using Unity and are creating a singleton GameManager, and actually I think the singleton pattern here might not be quite correct.

For example, if you use the code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46291568/10150864), actually there is virtually no possibility it does not have an instance if you treat your scene and gameobjects properly :)

Comment: I would rather see you include the salient "this" code in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you're kind of along the right lines here.

Unless you are in dire need of increasing performance, don't try to optimize, and if you do need to optimize, make sure you're doing it right (exceptions are more expensive that if statements, especially if you know they're going to happen)

The first example you've given, I can kind of get behind. You're making the assumption that something was initialized, and if it turns out it wasn't, throw an error. You're logging it, it's ok, you initialize it and you'll probably never have to worry about that exception again.

The second example you've given is a big no no. You should not use exceptions to fall into other logic in your application. Instead, in the Init() method, just always have the line 'instance = this', don't do the if statement. Once you know it's initialized, there should never be a reason for it to throw an exception when used.

Of course, don't go crazy with this, exceptions should only be used for exceptional circumstances. If you write your code and are thinking 'Hmm, so it could be either A scenario or B scenario, and in B scenario I want this to happen, so I'll throw an exception' that's completely the wrong line of thinking. Instead it should be 'Hmm, so all this will happen, but just in case something breaks, I'll put it in a try catch and log it, as who knows, I'm not infallible'

You can see how I've applied the above logic to your two examples,

Comment: Just to add on, as PMF's answer makes a good point. If it's something that makes your application NOT work and it should crash, rethrow the exception out of the catch block, which will make your application crash. But this time you'll have a nice little log message to make things easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are there when an "impossible" state occurs in your interfaces (Not the keyword - just the word), if you have to try - catch inside your business logic, your design is compromised.

In this case, you would likely gain both extendability, and readability, if you implement the slightly miss-named null-object pattern. (Should be called default object pattern)

And simply never be able to pass a null'ed interface to the method.

So:

```
public interface IGameObject {
   void Activate(instance initializable);
}

public class GameObjectDefault : IGameObject {

   public void Activate(instance initializable){
      --Does nothing on purpose
   }
}

public class GameObjectReal : IGameObject {

  private Instance _instance;

   public GameObjectReal(Instance instance)
   {
       _instance = instance;
   } 

   public void Activate(IGameObject initializable) {
      _instance.initializables.Add(initializable);
      --Do whatever you need to do to the object

   }
}
```

This is pseudo, because I can't see your whole system.
But this way, if you initialize all game objects as DefaultGameObjects, your activate or any other method, will just do nothing.

Now, there is no reason to check for null.
And no reason to do a try catch. Your impossible state, is now, literally, impossible.